# Converting Addresses to GeoPoint - serverside or clientside?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, parse-platform, geolocation

I am using swift and parse to build an app that finds the nearest restaurant to a user.

If I input all restaurant addresses into Parse, I would need to convert all the addresses into PFGeoPoints to calculate the distance from the current user's geopoint.

What is the correct approach to calculate PFGeoPoints for all addresses in the database? Should this be done serverside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, you should add a PFGeoPoint to your Restaurant object. It's fairly trivial to achieve using one of many available APIs on the market such as Google Places API. 
Once you have that you can just query for nearby Restaurants using:

```
[yourQuery whereKey:@"restaurantPoint" nearGeoPoint:currentLocation withinMiles:10];
```

Comment: Yeah, i get that. I'm just wondering whats the best way to convert all the addresses into PFGeoPoints? Is there a specific way of doing this within parse?

Comment: Just write a loop that utilizes Parse.framework and Google Places API which uploads all the data to Parse